# Applying a condition on ddply function

Tags: r

I want to not include the negative values of Time in calculation of Time average, however I still need to keep their corresponding cost and number values for calculating the mean cost and number cost. I was wondering how I can modify the below code:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
      4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("R1", "R2", 
      "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6"), class = "factor"), cost = c(123L, 12L, 
      14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 111L, 121L, 
      141L, 181L, 1611L), Time = c(123L, -12L, NA, -15L, NA, 17L, 18L, 
     -9L, 88L, 666L, 7L, 78L, 188L, 111L, 121L, 141L, 189L, 161L), 
      number = c(14L, 12L, 15L, 17L, NA, 17L, 22L, 95L, NA, 67L, 
      7L, 8L, 7L, 118L, NA, 140L, 180L, 1611L)), .Names = c("ID", 
      "cost", "Time", "number"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
A<-ddply(df,.(ID),summarise,  
   N.cost=sum(!is.na(cost)),Cost_Average=round(mean(cost,na.rm=TRUE),2), 
   N.Time=sum(!is.na(Time)),Time_Average= round(mean(Time,na.rm=TRUE),2),
   N.n=sum(!is.na(number)),number_Average= round(mean(number,na.rm=TRUE),2))
```

Comment: A reproducible example would help here. In the mean time, you can try `Time_Average= round(mean(Time[Time >= 0],na.rm=TRUE),2)`

Comment: @docendo discimus: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I provided an example.

Comment: I modified your input data so that a) it's easy to copy and b) columns have sensible classes. You can use what I suggested in my first comment or take a look at akrun's answer below where he uses `dplyr` - the successor of `plyr` for `data.frame`s.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(N.Time = sum(!is.na(Time)),
             Time_Average = round(mean(Time[Time >=0 & !is.na(Time)]), 2))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time